# Option value need to be different, Instead of being same as displayed in Select Box

Tags: javascript

I am having little issue in java script generated select box, The problem is that i want to display PK - 1, PK - 2 .. in select box but the value which will be attached to them will be different. For example for PK - 1 , I want to have 1 as it value, Similarly for PK - 2 i want to have 2 as its passing value. But here in this code the script is passing PK - 1 as it is. As i am new to java Script, I do not know how to do it. Here is my code

```
function categoryInput(data){
    var category_vals = document.getElementById("categroy_renew");
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "PK - "+data[i].cat,data[i].cat;
category_vals.add(option);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using : category_vals[category_vals.options.length] = new Option( Value, Text );

Comment: @jeff TIL about `new Option` thanks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option . To return the favor, you don't need to do `arrName[arrName.length] = value;` , you can do `arrName.push(value)`

Comment: Op, you have a `,` between `data[i].cat` and it repeating again. A comma means "evaluate the left side, discard it and then use the right side" - for example: `1+2,2` is equal 2. That's probably not intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function categoryInput(data) {
    var category_vals = document.getElementById("categroy_renew");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = "PK - " + data[i].cat;
        option.value = "" + data[i].cat;
        category_vals.add(option);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the value on your option like you are setting the text:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "PK - " + data[i].cat, data[i].cat; // Why are you doing this part?
option.value = data[i].cat;                       // Just need "PK - " + data[i].cat;
category_vals.add(option);
```

As mentioned in comments there is an easier way to create new options, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1689708/1402923).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're forgetting to set the "value" of each option.
Like you've set option.text, try to set option.value for each option.